# How to make 12 ListView items if i have an Array and only number 12 in it?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I just started learning Java and Android development and I need to make 12 listView items that will be shown on Android Mobile screen.I also have an Array that have only number 12 in it.
So i need to make 12 listView  items out of this Array that have only number 12 in it.

```
public void done(List<ParseObject> weeks, ParseException e) {
        if (e== null){
            //show vezbaci
            mWeeks = weeks;
            Integer[] number_weeks = new Integer [mWeeks.size()];
            int i = 0;
            for(ParseObject NumberOfWeeks : mWeeks){
                number_weeks[i] = NumberOfWeeks.getInt("numberOfWeeks");
                i++;
            }

            ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>
                    (Week.this, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,
                            number_weeks);
            setListAdapter(adapter);


        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

numberOfWeeks has a Value of 12.This adapter shows only one listView item "12" . 
But i need it to print 12 item like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 .

Comment: have you checked that your weeks list (List<ParseObject> weeks) is not of size 1? or why not creating your adapter as:  ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>
                    (Week.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            number_weeks);

Comment: I tried  ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer> (Week.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, number_weeks); But i got the same result.Only one list view item that have a value of 12.Not 12 list items with the values 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12.Thanks for your answer and time. :-)

Comment: Try 

`ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>
                    (Week.this, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,
                            i);`

Comment: so as I stated before, did you try debugging and checking the size of your array before setting the adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to apply basic debugging to see the size of the array you are working with like so:

```
public void done(List<ParseObject> weeks, ParseException e) {
        if (e== null){
            //show vezbaci
            mWeeks = weeks;
            int sizeOfArray = mWeeks.size();
            Log.d(TAG, "Size of mWeeks " + sizeOfArray);
            if (sizeOfArray > 1){
                Integer[] number_weeks = new Integer [sizeOfArray];
                int i = 0;
                for(ParseObject NumberOfWeeks : mWeeks){
                    number_weeks[i] = NumberOfWeeks.getInt("numberOfWeeks");
                    i++;
                }

                ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>
                        (Week.this, android.R.layout.simple_selectable_list_item,
                                number_weeks);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            }


        }else{
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: that is pretty much what I suggested but he hasn't tried yet so it seems.

Comment: Yes i tried that and the size of the array(mWeeks) is 1.I  forget to mentiom that on my firts answer to you.